# antlr matching token instead of text

Tags: antlr

I'm struggling to understand ANTLR and I'm trying to match this sentence:

```
name "some_name" module ....
```

The grammare file looks like this one :

```
swdFile : nameDecl  module* EOF;

nameDecl:  NAME DBL_QUOTE appName DBL_QUOTE;

appName: TEXT;

module: MODULE;


DBL_QUOTE : '\"';
NAME:'name';
MODULE:'module';
TEXT : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
```

This works fine, but with a small glitch that I can't seem to understand. If I try to parse this text, it fails because it matches the quoted text as a token:

```
name "module" module ...
```

Why is that? I specifically told it that what is between quotes is plain text and it should match the TEXT token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer is not being driven by the parser. So your input `"module"` gets tokenized as follows:

- `DBL_QUOTE`
- `MODULE`
- `DBL_QUOTE`

and is therefor not matched by the parser rule `nameDecl:  NAME DBL_QUOTE appName DBL_QUOTE;`. String literals are usually handled by the lexer, in which case you won't have an issue:

```
...

nameDecl : NAME STRING;

...    

STRING : '"' ~'"'* '"';
NAME   : 'name';
MODULE : 'module';

...
```

Comment: OK so lexer 'tokenizes' my input in 'independent' somehow with the parser. Thanks for the answer Bart, I need to move the quotes inside a token so antlr can properly identify it as a quoted `STRING`. Still why does antlr try to match every TOKEN and only after that it matches the parser grammar?

Comment: How would I treat the case when I want to parse something without the quotes --> `name module module` , and I would like the first occurence of module to be the name and the second module to be well.. the module token . Thanks !